# Java adding 2 objects in a JFrame but only 1 is showing

Tags: java, layout, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I know this question is asked often in stackoverflow. And i know there is a page on oracle about LayoutManagers but i dont understand how to use it? Can someone help me with my code? Im trying to make a game with 2 squares trying to catch each other. It's not finished yet. I will finish it once i solve the graphical issues. Do i need a JPanel to do it? Thanks in advance!

JFrame class

```
package catchmev2;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

/**
 *
 * @author MertKarakas
 */
public class CatchMeV2 implements ActionListener{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setTitle("CatchMe.V2");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //Adding square 1
        RedSquare r = new RedSquare();
        frame.getContentPane().add(r);
        r.setFocusable(true);
        r.requestFocusInWindow();
        //Adding square 2
        BlueSquare b = new BlueSquare();
        frame.getContentPane().add(b);
        b.setFocusable(true);
        b.requestFocusInWindow();


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
}
```

First square class

```
package catchmev2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author MertKarakas
 */
public class RedSquare extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

int x = 20; int y = 20;
int velX = 0; int velY = 0;
Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

public RedSquare(){
    addKeyListener(this);      
    tm.start();
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 25);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    x = x + velX;
    y = y + velY;
    if (x < 0) {
        velX = 0;
        x = 0;
    }
    if (x > width - 50) {
        velX = 0;
        x = width - 50;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
        velY = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    if (y > height - 40) {
        velY = 0;
        y = height - 40;
    }
    repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int code = e.getKeyCode();
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        velX = -4;
        velY = 0;
        System.out.println("sex1");
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        velX = 0;
        velY = -4;
        System.out.println("sex2");
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        velX = 4;
        velY = 0;
        System.out.println("sex3");
    }
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 4;
        System.out.println("sex4");
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
    }
}
```

Second square class

```
package catchmev2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author MertKarakas
 */
 public class BlueSquare  extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    int x = 700;
    int y = 600;
    int velX = 0;
    int velY = 0;
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
    int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight();

    public BlueSquare() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        tm.start();
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 25);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = x + velX;
        y = y + velY;
        if (x < 0) {
            velX = 0;
            x = 0;
        }
        if (x > width - 50) {
            velX = 0;
            x = width - 50;
        }
        if (y < 0) {
            velY = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        if (y > height - 40) {
            velY = 0;
            y = height - 40;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            velX = -4;
            velY = 0;
            System.out.println("sex1");
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            velX = 0;
            velY = -4;
            System.out.println("sex2");
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            velX = 4;
            velY = 0;
            System.out.println("sex3");
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            velX = 0;
            velY = 4;
            System.out.println("sex4");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: My first guess would be that 'two components cannot occupy the same layout constraint'.  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Try to set a minimum size for both JPanels.

Comment: @eckes How would that help?

Comment: maybe the panel is shown with size 0 because the other panel has maximum size... i am not sure what sizes FlowLayout actually assigns if you set none. Oh and you really should setVisible(true) as the last step. Otherwise it will layout before it is filled.

Comment: Looking at the code again, I think there is a general problem. It looks like you draw rectangles inside two JPanels. You dont use the FlowLayout, as your panels (should) occupy the whole container anyway. You should instead have only one canvas where you draw multiple rectangles. This also allows other optimizations like double buffering. Maybe this helps: http://www.cokeandcode.com/info/tut2d.html

Comment: @eckes Thank you the link kinda kinda helps me.